# Response.Listener not working

Tags: java, php, android, android-volley

i have a registration form for my app and the volley sends the request to the php file on the server and i see the user registered on the database, but the response listener does not receive the response which allows it to go back to homepage
this is my android code

```
if (rdPassword.equals(rdPassword2)) {
                if(rdEmail.matches(emailPattern)||rdEmail.matches(emailPattern2)){
                Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            System.out.println(response);
                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                            boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                            if (success) {
                                pd.dismiss();
                                Intent bktohome = new Intent(driver_registration.this, home.class);
                                bktohome.putExtra("company", rdCompany);
                                startActivity(bktohome);
                                finish();
                            } else {
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(driver_registration.this);
                                builder.setMessage("Register Failed")
                                        .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                        .create()
                                        .show();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                };
                DriverRegistration registerRequest = new DriverRegistration(rdUsername, rdPassword, rdName, rdEmail,
                        rdMobile, rdCompany, rdAddress, rdSSN, rdDLN,rdImage_encoded, responseListener);
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(driver_registration.this);
                queue.add(registerRequest);
                }
                else
                {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(driver_registration.this);
                    builder.setMessage("Wrong Email Format...")
                            .setNegativeButton("Retry",null)
                            .create()
                            .show();
                }
            } else {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(driver_registration.this);
                builder.setMessage(" Passwords do not match")
                        .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                        .create()
                        .show();
            }
```

DriverRegistration class

```
public class DriverRegistration extends StringRequest {
private static final String REGISTER_REQUEST_URL = "http://trackitfinal.hostei.com/registerDriver.php";
private Map<String , String> params;
public DriverRegistration(String username , String password , String name , String email  , int mobile , String company , String address ,
                              int SSN , int DLN,String rdImage_encoded, Response.Listener<String> listener)
{
    super(Method.POST,REGISTER_REQUEST_URL,listener,null);
    params=new HashMap<>();
    params.put("username",username);
    params.put("password",password);
    params.put("name",name);
    params.put("email",email);
    params.put("mobile",mobile+"");
    params.put("company",company);
    params.put("address",address);
    params.put("SSN",SSN+"");
    params.put("DLN",DLN+"");
    params.put("image",rdImage_encoded);
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getParams() {
    return params;
}
```

}

Comment: what is DriverRegistration ??

Comment: the class that sends the request to php, sec let me edit it into the question

Comment: I think you do very difficult code, i have send answer please check, you just add your URL and Parameters.

Answer (score 0):

check if your Api is working and sending proper response when User hit it or it may be just updating DB.and is there Api for getting user detail you can check it by hitting it or check it in the postman.

Comment: ya everything is working fine, just this one hickup in the whole application, i receive no response on my android there